# Visual Studio, C#: Как собрать *.MSI из командной строки командой devenv.exe ...?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, setup, msi

Уважаемые господа,

собираю классический "толстый msi", как установщик для проекта C# - WinForms - NET Framework 4.8.

Пользуюсь расширением для Visual Studio [Microsoft Visual Studio Installer Projects 2022](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=VisualStudioClient.MicrosoftVisualStudio2022InstallerProjects)

Из VS всё собирается прекрасно. Структура солюшена - простая, как морковка, один C# - проект, один - Setup - проект. и SLN, который их объединяет.

я несколько часов пытался сделать сборку MSI из командной строки. Практически любой запрос на эту тему приводит к советам типа [этого](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/cafed900-528a-43bb-9334-247e767d1236/building-deployment-projects-from-the-command-line-devenvexe?forum=csharpgeneral), [этого](https://www.codeproject.com/Questions/1236961/How-to-create-msi-and-setup-exe-file-from-the-comm) или [этого](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/0ec5951d-d194-449e-8d59-705706ec888a/building-setup-project-vdproj-from-command-line?forum=winformssetup)

То есть, "вам нужно написать команду вида

```
    "%devEnvDir%\devenv.exe" < ваш sln> /Rebuild /Project <ваш проект> "Release|Any CPU"
```

Видимо, дьявол кроется в деталях.

я пробовал выполнить этот совет с разными вариантами ключей, и лучшим результатом было, если я выполнял команду вида

```
    "%devEnvDir%\devenv.exe" D_T_setup.vdproj /Rebuild
```

и она... некоторое время что то загружала, а потом - ничего не делала.

Другим вариантом было появление окна с перечислением всех ключей команды `devenv` - такого же, как если написать `devenv.exe /?`

Как то это вопрос не очень освещен на просторах интернета, про то, как собрать проект "мышкой из VS" - есть десятки роликов на youtube, а вот как сделать подобное из командной строки - не могу найти работающего примера.

Нет ли у кого то подобного опыта? Что еще можно попробовать?

Спасибо заранее за советы!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/49632260/17025310, правда не совсем то.

Comment: @Kalmankantaja - спасибо за ссылку, но, мне кажется, она не имеет вообще никакого отношения к вопросу. Там рассматриваются преимущества установки при помощи msi и средства создания этих msi, и ни слова про создание из командной строки. У меня вопрос довольно узкий: как сделать сборку из командной строки?

Comment: Вас не смущает, что там написано ваш sln, ваш проект "%devEnvDir%\devenv.exe" < ваш sln > /Rebuild /Project < ваш проек т> "Release|Any CPU"

Comment: @Виктор - я думаю, что я как раз как то не понимаю синтаксиса этой команды. Чтобы его понять - нужен работающий пример. я перебрадл десятки вариантов, но все они - не работают. То есть - я говорю "вот солюшен, из него мне надо собрать проект такой то, ребилдом, в конфигурации релиз" - и оно просто не работает, и не говорит почему. Если Вы видите какую то явную ошибку - может быть, Вы мне на неё укажете?

Comment: Я понял так: "%devEnvDir%\devenv.exe" [имя вашего].sln /Rebuild /Project [имя вашего].csproj "Release|Any CPU"   возможно надо путь к csproj добавить. Запускать из каталога где sln

Comment: @Виктор - не, CS - проект собирать не надо. Его прекрасно msbuild собирает. я бы даже не возражал против полной пересборки солюшена, ради того, чтобы setup собрался - но так оно тоже не работает... а тот проект, который мне надо собирать - имеет расширение .vdproj

Comment: devenv /build Release /project [путь\файл].vdproj

Comment: @Виктор - Чего то не хватает... "Invalid Command Line.": https://junecat.ru/Storage/oth/invalid.png

Comment: /ProjectConfig "Release|Any CPU" не хватает

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Очень круто.

я научился это делать.

Мне во многом помогло обсуждение в комментариях к моему вопросу, но окончательный рецепт оказался чуть сложнее.

Вот основные моменты.

1. Нужно использовать "командную строку от самого VIsual Studio" - об этом иногда  забывают, см картинку.

[image: картинка 1]

2. После этого, по следам обсуждения с Виктором в комментариях, мне удалось родить команду

   ```
    devenv TradeEngine2.sln /Rebuild Release /project D_T_setup\D_T_setup.vdproj
   ```

выполнение которой заканивается... барабанная дробь... ошибкой вот такого вот вида:

```
1>          1 file(s) copied.
1>          1 file(s) copied.
1>          1 file(s) copied.
------ Starting pre-build validation for project 'TradeEngineSetup' ------
ERROR: An error occurred while validating.  HRESULT = '8000000A'
------ Pre-build validation for project 'TradeEngineSetup' completed ------
2>------ Rebuild All started: Project: TradeEngineSetup, Configuration: Release ------
========== Rebuild All: 1 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 skipped ==========
```

[image: картинка 2]

3. Эта ошибка выводит нас на [обсуждение десятилетней давности](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8648428/an-error-occurred-while-validating-hresult-8000000a), в котором говорится о том, что "да-да, эта ошибка там и будет возникать, при сборке из командной строки, а чтобы её побороть - есть специальная утилита"

Утилиту надо найти у себя на диске, по имени `DisableOutOfProcBuild.exe`, запустить с правами админа, и тогда та же самая команда сборки

```
    devenv TradeEngine2.sln /Rebuild Release /project D_T_setup\D_T_setup.vdproj
```

начинает чудасным образом работать!

**Фанфары, слава MS, занавес!**

*Маленькое дополнение.*

Так как я через пару недель полностью забуду, как я это делал, я решил расшифровать первый шаг:

Итак, у нас есть в винде шоткат, котрый называется `Developer Command Prompt for VS 2022`

Это *.bat-файл ( sDevCmd.bat ), который устанавливает переменные окрежения и делает еще кое-какую работу. Нам надо вызвать его в самом начале из того *.bat-файла, который осуществляет сборку.

Я делаю это буквально следующим кодом:

```
    SET mydir=%~dp0
    cd C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Professional\Common7\Tools\
    call VsDevCmd.bat
    cd %mydir%
    devenv Tasker.sln /Rebuild Release /project "Tasker.Manager Setup\Tasker.Manager Setup.vdproj"
```

Здесь я в первой строке запоминаю такущую директорию, во второй строке перехожу в папку, где лежит sDevCmd.bat, в третьей строке выполняю его, в четвертой строке возвращаюсь обратно и наконец, в пятой строке - запускаю команду сборки.

Comment: Урраааааа!!!!! :)))

Comment: Не слава MS=) устал...